# Is there a way to trace the differences of a software in x64dbg?

Tags: disassembly, debugging, tracing, compare

Why does Immunity Debugger unable to start my application? I want to compare the differences of a software: Immunity Debugger can trace all assembly instruction with the *Add entries of all procedures* option (*Run trace --> Add entries of all procedures*) and saves it to *.txt file (*Run trace --> Log to file*). I want to know if I can do the same in x64dbg?